# Tycho: Debug Eclipse Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, tycho

Is there a way to create and debug an instance of Eclipse with the developed plugin?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA + Tycho to create an Eclipse Plugin.

I've found the "tycho-eclipserun" command but it does not start an instance of Eclipse.